# Simpy: Possible to do priority requests with filterstore?

Tags: python, simpy

I have a get request for one of two objects inside a filterstore that looks like this:

```
req = yield depot.get(lambda req: req['id'] == 's38' or 's39')
```

I want to make this particular request a priority so that it queue jumps all other requests. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if you create a sub-class of FilterStore similarly to PriorityQueue.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming this means editing the simpy library?

Comment: You don't need to edit simpy directly. Just subclass Store or Filter store and the functionality you need in your on app/lib.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that worked for me

```
import simpy
import bisect

class PriorityFilterStore(simpy.FilterStore):

    def _do_put(self, event):
        if len(self.items) < self._capacity:
            bisect.insort(self.items, event.item)
            event.succeed()

    def _do_get(self, event):
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            item = self.items[i]
            if event.filter(item):
                del self.items[i]   
                event.succeed(item)
                break
        return True
```